# Format text segments after returns and : in text

Tags: vba, ms-word, text-formatting

We have an array of documents to be formatted for better visibility.

As the output of our speech to text protocols we get a transcript.

The VBA script should format the text bold after every (return), and the text after a (:) not bold until the next return.

Example:
**Speaker1 Question1:** Answer Answer Answer
**Speaker1 Question2:** Answer Answer Answer

This is not working as expected already at the first part of the function.

```vb
Sub BoldGenerator()

    ' BoldGenerator Macro
    Selection.WholeStory

    'Make each .Method belong to Selection.Find for readability
    With Selection.Find
        'Set search criteria for break font
        .Text = "^l"
        'Find next occurrence
        .Execute
        
        Do While .Found
        Selection.Text = Selection.Font.Bold = True
        .Execute
        Loop
        
    End With
    
    '
    Call BoldGenerator
End Sub
```

Comment: An example of the final text version would be helpful. It is not clear how long your bold should last.

Comment: Hey, so example would be about his:

Speaker1 Question1: Answer Answer Answer  Speaker1 Question2: Answer Answer Answer  
  
In the example the Speaker aswell as the question should be bold, while the answer should not.

Unfortunately formatting rules do no apply to comments I guess.

Comment: You can always edit your question. First time I will do it for you, and you can verify if it's correct. If not, you can edit yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should bold everything between a (return) (actually it is a new line or a carriage return) and a colon (:)

It is not an easy VBA. Regular expressions are used which are not native in VBA, so we need to get them from VBScript library. We use regular expressions to find all instances starting after a carriage return and ending with a colon. Regular expressions are not able to change the format (to bold). So we need to use `.Find` method too. We again find what we previously found, but this time we make it bold.

You will see the first instance will not become bold, because it does not start after a carriage return.

```
Sub BoldGenerator()

Dim RE As Object
Dim REMatches As Object
Dim mch As Object

Selection.HomeKey wdStory
Selection.WholeStory

Set RE = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
With RE
  .Global = True
  .Pattern = "\r(.+?:)"
End With
Set REMatches = RE.Execute(Selection.Text)

If REMatches.Count > 0 Then
  Selection.HomeKey wdStory
    With Selection.Find
      .ClearFormatting
      .Forward = True
      .Format = False
      .MatchCase = True
      For Each mch In REMatches
        .Text = mch
        .Execute
        Selection.Font.Bold = True
        Selection.MoveRight wdCharacter
      Next
    End With
  Selection.HomeKey wdStory
End If

Set RE = Nothing
Set REMatches = Nothing
Set mch = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much, We would not have come to a solution I see now. Very much appreciated.